# read JSON array in servlet with json_simple

Tags: android, json, servlets

I have created a JSON array in my android code and post it to my servlet as below :

```
JSONArray Data = new JSONArray();

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
Data.put(String.valueOf(i));
}
}

URI url = new URI(serveraddress);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity DataEntity = new StringEntity(Data.toString());
DataEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
httpPost.setEntity(DataEntity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Then in my servlet, I use a reader to get the content from the http request as below :

```
StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
try {
BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
jb.append(line);
} catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }
```

Now i am not sure how to create the JSON array from this string. The servlet is hosted in a jetty web server with the json_simple library. The JSONArray class only has an empty constructor, unlike the one in the Android bundle which has a constructor with a string parameter as well. So could some one give me a hint on how to create the JSON array from the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = (JsonElement) parser.parse(line); 
JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: JsonElement cannot be resolved to a type. Which package is that in? Are you referring to gson? I am using json_simple

Comment: @George-Brighton Thanks for formatting the JSONParser back to JsonParser. I was using the org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser instead of com.google.gson.JsonParser in my code unintentionally and it was crashing. You saved me a lot of trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            out = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(out );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            jObj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
                jObj.put("array",ja);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e1.toString());
            }
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: You also must be referring to the gson library since json_simple does not have a JSONArray(JSONObject) constructor. Thanks, will give it a try.